# SSH connection to AWS EC2 servers terminate often

Tags: ssh, linux

SSH connection to AWS EC2 servers terminate often, what configuration needs to be modified so that we could minimize the remote shell from being terminated.

Comment: Double post. (The other is http://superuser.com/questions/581220/ssh-connection-to-aws-ec2-servers-terminate-often )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.ssh/config file

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: But it doesn't seem to be worked effectively. I am facing the same issue frequently.

Comment: Please let me know the answer for this query. I don't find the above answer works good and i also tried this answer as follows:

On the server, login as root and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add the line:

`ClientAliveInterval 60`

man sshd_config:


You'll need to restart the sshd for it to come into effect.

Alternatively on the client edit /etc/ssh/ssh_config (if you have root and want it for all users) or ~/.ssh/config and add the line:

`ServerAliveInterval 60`
 but doesn't seems to be worked

Comment: Try adding `Protocol 2` at the top of your ~/.ssh/config file - `ServerAliveInterval` is a SSH2 only feature. Also, try putting all these settings indented under a `Host *` line and see if that helps.